# Redirect uri error when aunthenticating with VK.com

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, vk

I am trying to develop login with vk.com feature for our website. And testing it locally. In app I have given

> http://127.0.0.1/

as base domain. In website during authorization it is requesting url:

> https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1/vk/login/check/&state=trackid=XXXX..

In callback url, I am calling

> https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=XXXX&client_secret=YYYY&redirect_uri=redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1/vk/login/check/aaa/bbbb&code=

But its not loading VK website for logging in. It shows error

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"redirect_uri has wrong
>   domain, check application settings"}.

Dont know whats wrong. Any help?

Earlier when testing to request code and accesstoken manually, I had given domain in app as https://www.example.com and used https://www.example.com as redirect url when requesting code and access token. At that time it had worked.

Now how can I test it when our website is running locally? Please help

Comment: as a quick workaround you can change back to using `example.com` domain in your redirect_uri while adding line `127.0.0.1       example.com` to `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` on linux and `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on windows). This line tells your OS to resolve example.com domain name to localhost.

Comment: I couldnt do that because flask was generating this url dynamically. So it will be redirecting to 127.0.0.1 only. But I could solve the issue by using https to run server and also changing base domain to https

Answer (score 0):

You should open your 8000 port and put to "redirect_uri" your ip. But it's not exactly work, because u should have your own host

Answer (score 0):

go to your app setting in VK set your redirect-uri http://127.0.0.1:5000/anything (port is important/use Port that you are using according to server hosting service). then try it.